# Struggling with the math behind this

Tags: homework

I have been trying to figure out how the wire resistance intersects with the rest of my calculations. First weeks of Circuits and I am lost.

[image]

Comment: Show some effort on this. You show no calculations.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Wire resistances are a part of the total resistance of the circuit. To handle the case you must know Ohm's law, Kirchoff's laws and how to combine parallel and series resistors to one equivalent resistance. Knowing these is not enough. One must see how to apply them. This is as complex as it can be without needing groups of equations. The next step after this is to solve circuits with  equation groups which have many unknown voltages or currents..

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. For homework questions you need to tell us (by editing the question) what you've tried and where you got stuck so we can help you. If you've had a few weeks of circuits you should have been introduced to Ohm's law, combining resistors in series and parallel and Kirchoff's voltage and current laws which will let you solve this problem.

Comment: Also, your question title should explain the topic of the question to attract people that are knowledgeable / interested in the subject. "Struggling with the math behind this" doesn't tell us anything about the fact that the question is about resistor networks. There's an [edit] link below your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a series of equivalent circuits, you can find the voltages at the required nodes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjKPKM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that the concept is flawed since the resistance of an incandescent bulb changes with applied voltage. However, that's beyond the scope of question.